# Why nnoremap doesn't work with CtrlP and nmap does work? - VIM

Tags: vim, ctrlp

I have this in my **.vimrc**

```
nnoremap <leader>p :CtrlP<CR><C-\>w
```

I change all **nmap** to **nnoremap** in my **.vimrc** and everything works fine except this one:

```
nnoremap <leader>p :CtrlP<CR><C-\>w
```

With `nmap <leader>p :CtrlP<CR><C-\>w` it does automatically insert word into **CtrlP** and with **nnoremap** it doesn't, I get blank field, like I just pressed **Ctrl-P**.

Why it doesn't work with **nnoremap**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create a mapping with `nnoremap`, it does not consider your prior mappings when resolving what to do. In other words, if you had previously mapped any of these:

```
<CR>
<C-\>
w
```

Then those maps would be ignored in your `<leader>p` mapping, and instead the default action of those keystrokes would be used.

As far as I know, `<C-\>` has no default action, so I would suspect you have mapped it (or you are relying on a mapping that another plugin has added), but that mapping is not being taken into account here.

Comment: Thank you very much for a great explanation.